# Select FrameSize for video with logo in FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming

I'm using this command to stream video with 1920*1080 frame size:

```
ffmpeg -re -i test.mp4 -vf scale=1920*1080 -f mpegts udp://127.0.0.1:port
```

but when I want to stream images with video like this:

```
ffmpeg -re -i test.mp4 -vf scale=1920*1080 -i logo.png -ignore_loop 0 -i 
test6.gif -filter_complex "[0][1]overlay=10:10[a];[a][2]overlay=90:90" -f 
mpegts udp://127.0.0.1:port
```

the command line display this error: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lK8IE.png)

How can I choose frame size when I stream video with image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few problems with your command:

1. Some of your options are in the wrong location. Option placement matters:

   ```
   ffmpeg [input1 options] -i input1 [input2 options] -i input2 [output options] output
   ```
2. Do all filtering in one filtergraph:

   ```
   ffmpeg -re -i test.mp4 -i logo.png -ignore_loop 0 -i test6.gif
   -filter_complex "[0][1]overlay=10:10[a];[a][2]overlay=90:90,scale=1920:1080"
   -f mpegts udp://127.0.0.1:port
   ```